# Determine whether or not a user has allowed local notifications in iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to determine whether or not a user has allowed local notifications. The below method does a good job at returning the notification settings that have been allowed by the user in iOS 8 onwards.

**Question:**

What code must I add to check whether or not a user has allowed local notifications in iOS 7? What is the fallback method for checking in iOS 7?

(And yes, I do care about customers that are still on iOS 7.)

**Code:**

```
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        if let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() {
            if settings.types.contains(.None) {
                print("None")
            }
            if settings.types.contains(.Badge) {
                print("Badge")
            }
            if settings.types.contains(.Sound) {
                print("Sound")
            }
            if settings.types.contains(.Alert) {
                print("Alert")
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback for iOS 7
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var notifyTypes: UIRemoteNotificationType = UIApplication.sharedApplication().enabledRemoteNotificationTypes()
```

Then you can simply check the value of notifyTypes.

Here's a link for the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623075-enabledremotenotificationtypes

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but doesn't appear to work. Please correct me, but this answer focuses on remote notifications. I'm after a solution to determine whether local notifications are switched on or off in iOS 7 Settings.